# java Some usage questions about "? super Fruit"

Tags: java

I got a problem ,eg :

**Fruit Class**

```
public class Fruit extends Food {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Plate<? super Fruit> plate = new Plate<>(new Food());
        plate.setItem(new Apple());
        plate.setItem(new Food());
    }


    static class Apple extends Fruit {

    }
}
```

**Food Class**

```
public class Food {
}
```

**Plate Class**'

```
public class Plate<T> {

    private T item;

    public Plate(T t) {
        item = t;
    }

    public T getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(T item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why

```
Plate<? super Fruit> plate = new Plate<>(new Food())
```

not error

but

```
plate.setItem(new Food())
```

is error

What is the difference between these two methods?

-that all, thanks!

Comment: `Plate<? super Fruit>` should be read as "a Plate that it is known to be safe to add a Fruit to". It doesn't mean it's *not* safe to add Food to it; merely that the compiler can't prove that it will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things happening on this line:

```
Plate<? super Fruit> plate = new Plate<>(new Food());
```

`new Plate<>(new Foo())` creates a new instance of `Plate`. The generic parameter here is inferred to be `Food`, so the right hand side creates a `Plate<Food>` object.

The second thing is that this object is assigned to `plate`. `plate` can be a `Plate<T>` as long as `T` is `Fruit` or a super class of `Fruit`. Is `Food` a superclass of `Fruit`? Yes, so the right hand side can be assigned to `plate`.

On this line however:

```
plate.setItem(new Food())
```

You are setting a plate's item. That `plate` could be a plate of anything, as long as it is `Fruit` or a superclass of `Fruit`. This means that passing a `Food` object wouldn't work. Why? Well, what if `plate` is actually a `Plate<Fruit>`? It could be, couldn't it? The compiler doesn't know.

So the only thing you can pass to `plate.setItem` are `Fruit` and subclasses of `Fruit`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a classical case of [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

When using `super` here, you created something that can get consumed but not produce anything to it of the type specified. This is exactly what you were trying to do.

To simplify it a bit, here is an example of what you could do with your object.

```
Plate<? super Fruit> plate = new Plate<>(...);
Fruit fruit = plate.getItem(); // GOOD !
Food food = plate.getItem(); // GOOD ! Because even a Fruit can be assigned to a Food reference so it's OK !
Apple apple = plate.getItem(); // BAD ! No insurance it is an apple, we just know it is a Fruit

plate.setItem(new Fruit()); // GOOD !
plate.setItem(new Apple()); // GOOD ! Because we know it's always a Fruit, and Apple extends Fruit
plate.setItem(new Food()); // BAD ! No insurance we're not dealing with a Fruit, and a Food object can't be assigned to a Fruit reference (without casting)
```